# Offset block colour behind text

Tags: html, css, text, colors, styles

Im looking for a way to style text like this :

[image: text styles]

I have tried h2::before pseudo class however it adds the style to the whole h2 element rather than the text so will not style over **multiple lines**.

```
h2{
  font-size: 48px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 0.9;
}

h2::before {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 21px;
    left: -10px;
    background: rgba(229, 57, 53, 100);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Thoughts on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can make the title `display:inline` then use **linear-gradient** like this :

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff 60%, #ff9797 55%);
}
```

```html
<h2>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</h2>
```

Comment: This is a great solution and works in your code snipped however for some reason its still won't run across multiple lines on my h2. Its only appearing on the bottom line.

`<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-2">
   <h2>Combatting your wasted time</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>`

 css


`h2{
  font-size: 48px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 0.9;
  background-image:linear-gradient(white 60%,red 55%);
}`

Comment: @SimonRayRayAmor the issue is with line-height, remove it ... and you need to make h2 **inline** like i did

Comment: @SimonRayRayAmor you are missing `display: inline;`